# Reading cookies on main page does not work

Tags: jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I know this is a weird question. I am working on a web application where the welcome-file is a servlet (which collects data from database) and forward to JSP.
When I read cookies in the Main servlet,
**FireFox shows me File not found error,
Safari opens a popup to save a file named as "www.mydomain.co.uk",
Internet Explorer closes automatically**

And when I read the cookies in JSP scriplet as follows,

```
//Read cookies and check if log in info is correct
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
    { 
        Cookie c = cookies[i];
        if (c.getName().equals("__iaqwc"))
        {
            if(!c.getValue().equals(""))
            {
                info = c.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
```

It does not read cookies first time and does not show anything on the page (which I am generating usnig javascript), and when I refresh the page then is shows me the stuff and reads cookies.
I am reading cookies inside the "head tag" and this is happening only for main page other pages are working fine. And Also works fine on the local server but when I upload on the live server the said problem occurs.

Any Idea what could be the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first request, the returned value of `request.getCookies()` might be `null`.

```
 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
 if(cookies!=null) {
    //code here
 }
```